# Predictive formula

Tags: statistics, regression, probability, prediction, markov-chains

I would like to predict how much we should keep in a box "Magical-box"

"Magical-box" Should have the ability to predict the value of the next deposit in it :

For Example :

```
DepositNbr    Coins      MagicBox
1              6            6
2              4            4  
3              10           13    <==> the prediction process may starts from the third deposit
4              13           8
5              8            23
6              23            2
7              2            ...
```

is there any way to perform this prediction based on the past or the present ?,any formula ( markov Chain , normal distribution,Regression... ) is welcomed